# constexpr default constructor for struct with uninitialized member works only when templated

Tags: c++, templates, default, constexpr, c++17

It seems that I am allowed to explicitly default a constexpr default constructor with an uninitialized member *if and only if the struct is a template*. This is true even if the template struct is instantiated.

Is this correct?

**Example:**

```
struct SFoo
  {
    constexpr SFoo() =default; // disallowed
    int x;
  };

template <typename tTYPE>
struct SBar
  {
    constexpr SBar() =default; // accepted
    int x;
  };

int main(int argc, char const* const argv[])
  {
    SBar<int> bar; // also accepted
    constexpr SBar<int> bar2; // disallowed (correctly)

    return 0;
  }
```

**LLVM Output:**

```
3:3: error: defaulted definition of default constructor is not constexpr
constexpr SFoo() =default;
```

Both LLVM and GCC reject `SFoo` and accept `SBar`

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#6

Comment: @T.C. If you have the answer, why don't you write a complete answer and link it to this documentation rather than just to give a link?

Comment: @Aracthor : That's how most questions work in `c++`/`c++11`/`c++14`. Trying to write a proper answer for every question is an inexhaustible endevour (speaking from experience).

Comment: @T.C. The spec link explains it, thanks. I had a look myself but couldn't find the relevant bits. I guess the reasoning is that if the member's was actually influenced by the template parameter(s), then you wouldn't want to force people to choose between removing constexpr or disallowing parameters that don't result in constexpr (which could lead to you having to write two separate structs to cover both cases).

Comment: Actually, the bottom part says: "If no specialization of the template would satisfy the requirements for a constexpr function or constexpr constructor when considered as a non-template function or constructor, the template is ill-formed." - a hard rule to check for I'm sure, but isn't this a clear case of when no specialization would satisfy the requirements? or does the "specialization" only apply to the ctor and not the struct itself?

Answer (score 0):

> if and only if

Let me give you the mathematician's answer. No. Trying to apply IIF to a 1300 page document is an NP hard problem.

> Is this correct?

Well your program is invalid either way.

> [dcl.init/7] If a program calls for the default initialization of an
>   object of a const-qualified type `T`, `T` shall be a class type with a
>   user-provided default constructor.

Doesn't matter if it's a template or not.

Comment: From T.C's link above, it appears IFF _is_ valid (assuming the ctor breaks no other rules). The example was meant to be invalid. Actually instantiating a const object wasn't part of the question.